# Real time or In memory database

Tags: in-memory-database, kdb, real-time-data

Is there any difference between real-time & in-memory DB, or its just same?

Also, kdb+ offers fast time series analysis on real time/ historical data; but is kdb+ a true Time-series database (like Opentsdb)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah the real-time database is an in-memory database so it is just the same. Kdb is particularly suited for time-series given the data is ordered in temporal order and can cope with high-frequency data.

You can run powerful analytics on top of kdb. I am actually using kdb at the moment for exactly the same purpose of Opentsdb;  collect disjoint physical measurements from different systems within FX trading to be used to create time series and for statistical analysis.